# gridview row access

Tags: view, grid, row

I have a gridview with two columns: `DocId` and `DocUrl`

`DocUrl` contails url of docs. Is there any way to access the access the `DocUrl` rows in one button click?

Once the button is clicked, it has to open the `DocUrl` and checks the string pattern. If it does not belong to that doc delete it, otherwise leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Use a LinkButton, on click of it , check its click event and check url, if its what you find open it using response.redirect or remove and update label